# I hope you're feeling well

Tags: greetings

Are "I hope you're feeling well." suitable words for common greeting? I mean doesn't it sound odd if there have been no troubles with friend's health and I just want to know if everything is fine with him?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no health problems you are alluding to, simply say, **"I hope you are well."**

Saying "I hope you're feeling well" does, as you intimated, give the impression that you are worried about your friend's health.

[Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/i-hope-youre-doing-well/) also has some suggestions for ways to avoid this style of greeting altogether, as it tends to be overused and may come off as insincere.